# Domain for twiddle optimizer?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, parameters

I'm struggling to figure out how to set bounds (min/max) on a parameter optimization method. Twiddle is the optimization algorithm: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2uQ2BSzDvXs. How can I make sure p (the parameter) stays within a certain domain? Below is my Twiddle implementation in Python:

```
def twiddle(objFunction, args, init=0.5, tolerance=0.00001, domain=(0,float("inf"))):
  """Optimize a single parameter given an objective function.

  This is a local hill-climbing algorithm. Here is a simple description of it:
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2uQ2BSzDvXs

  @param args       (tuple)   Arguments necessary for the objective function.

  @param tolerance  (float)   Number used to determine when optimization has
                              converged to a sufficiently good score.

  @param objFunction(function)Objective Function used to quantify how good a
                              particular parameter choice is.

  @param init       (float)   Initial value of the parameter.

  @param domain     (tuple)   Domain of parameter values, as (min, max).

  @return (dict) Contains:
        "parameter" (float)   Threshold that returns the largest score from the
                              Objective function.

        "score"     (float)   The score from the objective function given the
                              threshold.
  """
  pastCalls = {}
  x = init
  delta = 0.1
  bestScore = objFunction(x, args)

  pastCalls[x] = bestScore

  while delta > tolerance: #and x >= domain[0]+tolerance and x <= domain[1]-tolerance:
    x += delta

    if x not in pastCalls:
      score = objFunction(x, args)
      pastCalls[x] = score

    score = pastCalls[x]

    if score > bestScore:
      bestScore = score
      delta *= 2

    else:
      x -= 2*delta

      if x not in pastCalls:
        score = objFunction(x, args)
        pastCalls[x] = score

      score = pastCalls[x]

      if score > bestScore:
        bestScore = score
        delta *= 2
      else:
        x += delta
        delta *= 0.5

    print "Parameter:", x
    print "Best score:", bestScore
    print "delta:", delta
    print

  return {"parameter": x,
          "score": bestScore}
```

E.g. I'd like to run the sine function as `objFunction` but with the domain set to [0, 2*pi].

Comment: After each `x +=` or `x -=`, have `x` set to the lower bound if it's gone below it, to the upper bound if it's gone above it (I'm not sure but for stability you may need to recompute `delta` accordingly in such cases).  Seems too simple as an answer, which is why this is just a comment:-)

Comment: @AlexMartelli doesn't quite work because the step size `delta` still gets adjusted as if the algorithm is moving in the right direction (even though it may be heading out of bounds). I.e. hard setting x to the max tells the algorithm it should keep increasing x.

Comment: that's why I mused that you might have to recompute `delta`.  But essentially the behavior you describe would be as expected when the max is at a boundary -- recomputing `delta` eventually ends up zeroing it as it keep trying to push `x` out of bounds, thus the `while` loop exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it! Similar to @AlexMartelli's comment, the algorithm needs to guard against going out of bounds at each increment/decrement to x. To maintain the core functionality of the hill-climbing algorithm, the step size `delta` has to be adjusted to half the distance between the current location and the outer boundary. This way the algorithm still favors moving in the direction of the boundary, can get there if the max is at the boundary, and can move back away from the boundary if necessary. Code is below:

```
def twiddle(objFunction, args, init=0.5, tolerance=0.00001, domain=(float("-inf"), float("inf"))):
  """Optimize a single parameter given an objective function.

  This is a local hill-climbing algorithm. Here is a simple description of it:
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2uQ2BSzDvXs

  @param args       (tuple)   Arguments necessary for the objective function.

  @param tolerance  (float)   Number used to determine when optimization has
                              converged to a sufficiently good score.

  @param objFunction(function)Objective Function used to quantify how good a
                              particular parameter choice is.

  @param init       (float)   Initial value of the parameter.

  @param domain     (tuple)   Domain of parameter values, as (min, max).

  @return (dict) Contains:
        "parameter" (float)   Threshold that returns the largest score from the
                              Objective function.

        "score"     (float)   The score from the objective function given the
                              threshold.
  """
  pastCalls = {}
  x = init
  delta = 0.1
  bestScore = objFunction(x, args)

  pastCalls[x] = bestScore

  while delta > tolerance:

    # Keep x within bounds
    if x+delta > domain[1]:
      delta = abs(domain[1] - x) / 2
    x += delta

    if x not in pastCalls:
      score = objFunction(x, args)
      pastCalls[x] = score

    score = pastCalls[x]

    if score > bestScore:
      bestScore = score
      delta *= 2

    else:
      # Keep x within bounds
      if x-delta < domain[0]:
        delta = abs(domain[0] - x) / 2
      x -= 2*delta

      if x not in pastCalls:
        score = objFunction(x, args)
        pastCalls[x] = score

      score = pastCalls[x]

      if score > bestScore:
        bestScore = score
        delta *= 2
      else:
        x += delta
        delta *= 0.5

    print "Parameter:", x
    print "Best score:", bestScore
    print "Step size:", delta
    print

  return {"parameter": x,
          "score": bestScore}
```